Rank $1$ locally free quotient sheaves of the cotangent bundle restricted to a smooth generic curve
Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{K}$ such that $K_X$ (the canonical bundle) is ample.
For $m\gg0$ there exists $D_1,\dotsc,D_{n-1}\in|mK_X|$ such that $C=D_1\cap\dotsc\cap D_{n-1}$ is a smooth curve.
Let $\Omega^1_X$ be the cotangent bundle of $X$, then $\Omega^1_C$ (the cotangent bundle of $C$) is a rank $1$ locally free quotient sheaf of $\Omega^1_{X\vert C}$.

Is $\Omega^1_C$ the unique (up to isomorphism) rank $1$ locally free quotient sheaf of $\Omega^1_{X\vert C}$?


If the answer is no, how can one classify (up to isomorphism) these quotient sheaves of $\Omega^1_{X\vert C}$?


This is not true in general. For instance, let $X = C_1 \times C_2$ be a product of two curves of genus larger than 1. Then
$$
\Omega_X = p_1^*\Omega_{C_1} \oplus p_2^*\Omega_{C_2} 
$$
is the sum of two line bundles, hence the same us true for its restriction to $C$.

Ok @Sasha, this asnwers to the first question. What can we say about the second question?

In what terms do you want to classify these? I think this is a particular case of the question of classifying line bundle quotients of a vector bundle $E$ and there is nothing specific about $\Omega_X$. Rephrased geometrically, this is the question of classifying sections of a projective bundle over a curve.
